# Audio stopped working in Xine in Debian

Tags: debian, audio

Recently sound stopped working in all the Xine-based applications. I get the error: `the audio device is unavailable`. I am using latest Debian Testing with KDE. I haven't been fiddling with the configuration recently, just doing the updates.

Comment: Probably something has grabbed the sound device. You could try to identify this. One common thing that screws stuff up is browsers, so try closing your browsers. Otherwise, try logging out and back in, and if that doesn't work, doing a reboot.

Comment: Yeah, I tried a reboot. I will try another reboot and play something before I run xine. However, mplayer based players work just fine, I am wondering what might be the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xine is not being developed anymore. Change to another phonon-backend.

I.E. after that Xine problem you've have described, I'm running phonon-backend-vlc flawlessly.

Comment: Xine isn't developed anymore? What, the project stopped since the last release two weeks ago?